# Deleting everything right and bottom of the specific string or number

Tags: mysql

I m working lot of on this file I have lot of numbers connected with sign =
for example i have lot of rows like this.

```
1day

01234567890123456=00000000000000000000? 120:15:7 theNameOfTheArticleAndNumber

120:15:13 signA1

120:15:14 signB2

120:15:18 signC3

120:15:53 signD4

120:15:58 signE5

0123456789012888=00000000000000000001?  120:20:15 theNameOfTheArticleAndNumber

120:20:20 signA1

120:20:21 signB2

120:20:22 signC3

120:20:27 signD4

120:20:58 signE5

2day


01234567890123333=00000000000000000000? 120:15:7 theNameOfTheArticleAndNumber

120:15:13 signA1

120:15:14 signB2

120:15:18 signC3

120:15:53 signD4

120:15:58 signE5

01234567890199993=00000000000000000001? 120:20:15 theNameOfTheArticleAndNumber

120:20:20 signA1

120:20:21 signB2

120:20:22 signC3

120:20:27 signD4

120:20:58 signE5
```

What I want  to delete everything in the file right and bottom of the number
01234567890123456=00000000000000000000, 0123456789012888=00000000000000000001 
I want to have result in the notepad++ like this:

:::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::;;

```
1day


01234567890123456=00000000000000000000

0123456789012888=000000000000000000001


2day


01234567890123333=00000000000000000000

01234567890199993=00000000000000000001
```

:::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::

What replace command I have to use to have result like this. I m new in this program. 
Thanks in advance 
Kind regards
Nenad

---

Yes you are appsolutely right I want number in front of the ? saved yes. And to have a result like that I describe

1day

2343445665465465465=3425432543253425

1231231231312312313=1321313131313131

2day

32424324324234234324=42423432423424

23424242423232423334=23423432423432

Comment: Can I assume that you want any number that come before character '?'

Answer (score 0):

I find a solution. In Notepad++ First I select with altand left click mouse ? 120:15:7 theNameOfTheArticleAndNumber. I make a selection of 1000 lines (with? and 120:15:7 theNameOfTheArticleAndNumber). Than I go to Search/ Mark... and in mark type : than select Bookmark line and Search mode Normal. Left click on the button Mark All after this I m going on Search Bookmark Remove Bookmark lines and waaalaa i have erased all lines between numbers with =. After this I select all text than TextFx TextFx Edit Delete Surplus Blank Lines and after this I m formating just I want. If you find faster way please post. Thanks brothers Good bless you all

Kind regards Nenad